# Autodock prepare_receptor4.py script gives error while converting pdb files to pdbqt files

Tags: software-assistance, docking, from-chem-se, openbabel, autodock

Cross-posted on [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/167872/27342).

I am trying to make pdbqt files from pdb files for Docking with Autodock vina but getting errors while running the [prepare_receptor4.py](https://github.com/sahrendt0/Scripts/blob/master/docking_scripts/prepare_receptor4.py) script present in the [mgltools](https://www.scripps.edu/sanner/python/documentation/installationInstruction-binary-1-3alpha2.html) directory. The script converts pdb to pdbqt.

Usage

```
prepare_receptor4.py -r input.pdb -o output.pdbqt
```

`input.pdb` is the input pdb file, `output.pdbqt` is the output pdbqt file

I got the errors with [7RTT.pdb](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/7RTT) and [7WDA.pdb](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/7WDA) input files.

What are these errors and how can I resolve them? Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py", line 204, in <module>
    dict=dictionary)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/MoleculePreparation.py", line 558, in __init__
    version=version, delete_single_nonstd_residues=delete_single_nonstd_residues)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/MoleculePreparation.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.addCharges(mol, charges_to_add)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/MoleculePreparation.py", line 227, in addCharges
    chargeCalculator.addCharges(mol.allAtoms)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/MolKit/chargeCalculator.py", line 80, in addCharges
    babel.assignHybridization(atoms)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/PyBabel/atomTypes.py", line 143, in assignHybridization
    self.check_for_amides()
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/PyBabel/atomTypes.py", line 511, in check_for_amides
    if conn.babel_type=="Cac" or conn.babel_type=="Sox" or \
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/MolKit/molecule.py", line 409, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError('member %s not found'%member)
AttributeError: member babel_type not found
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py", line 204, in <module>
    dict=dictionary)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/MoleculePreparation.py", line 558, in __init__
    version=version, delete_single_nonstd_residues=delete_single_nonstd_residues)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/MoleculePreparation.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.addCharges(mol, charges_to_add)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/MoleculePreparation.py", line 227, in addCharges
    chargeCalculator.addCharges(mol.allAtoms)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/MolKit/chargeCalculator.py", line 80, in addCharges
    babel.assignHybridization(atoms)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/PyBabel/atomTypes.py", line 127, in assignHybridization
    a.babel_atomic_number = self.get_atomic_number(a.babel_type)
  File "/mnt/d/Download/mgltools/MGLToolsPckgs/PyBabel/atomTypes.py", line 103, in get_atomic_number
    (name,_name) )
ValueError: Could not find atomic number for A A
```

Comment: I'll copy my comment from Chem.SE: It might help if you were a bit clearer about what you've tried doing. My guess, given the warning about macOS Catalina (released in 2019) is that it's not well-maintained anymore and may not parse modern PDB files. There is a specific [support mailing list](https://autodocksuite.scripps.edu/support/).